# redis sismember check for multi user online

Tags: redis

iam use redis for get online user i just want to check if some user was online or not

first add user to onlines

> sadd online_users user_a
>
> (integer) 1

check if user_a is online

> sismember online_users user_a
>
> (integer) 1

my question its how to check for multi user if they are online some thing like

add soem users

> sadd online_users user_a
>
> (integer) 1
>
> sadd online_users user_b
>
> (integer) 1
>
> sadd online_users user_c
>
> (integer) 1

now i want to check for three users if they are online

> sismember online_users {user_a,user_b,user_c}

i dont know if this right but i want for multi user check return data like
{0,1,0} = {offline,online,offline}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to compare two sets.

1 - hold your 'contacts' in the 1st redis set

`SADD contacts:your_id  user_1 user_2 user_3 user_4`

2- make another set of all connected users

`SADD connected  user_1 user_2 user_3 user_6 user_78`

then use the command SINTER, it will give you the intersection between these two sets which means all of your contacts that are connected

```
SINTER connected contacts:your_id
```

just remember to keep the set 'connected' well updated... which is another story

hope this helps.

Comment: `SINTER` appears redundant - if you're already keeping `connected` up-to-date, just `SMEMBERS` or `SSCAN` it. In that sense, `connected` is practically the same at the OPs `online_users`... OTOH, your answer was accepted so perhaps I'm not getting this :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to call `SISMEMBER` for each user independently. In order to streamline the flow and make it more efficient, consider using Lua scripting. For example:

```
~$ redis-cli SADD online_users user_a user_b user_c
(integer) 3
~$ redis-cli --eval sismmember.lua online_users , user_a user_b user_c foo
1) (integer) 1
2) (integer) 1
3) (integer) 1
4) (integer) 0
~$ cat sismmember.lua 
local rep = {}
local ele = table.remove(ARGV,1)

while (ele) do
    rep[#rep+1] = redis.call('SISMEMBER',KEYS[1],ele)
    ele = table.remove(ARGV,1)
end

return rep
~$
```

Comment: Are you using the cli or something else?

Comment: i just use redis and use it with php or node.js

Comment: So you'll need to use PHP's or Node's practice for loading and running the script. Usually this is just a matter of sending the script itself (not the filename) to the client's EVAL method.

Comment: Of course, once you've got the script running like you want, use SCRIPT LOAD and EVALSHA for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

After redis v6.2.0, we can use `SMISMEMBER` to check if multiple keys are present in a set

```
SMISMEMBER online_users user1 user2
```

response will be

```
1) (integer) 1 
2) (integer) 0
```

ref: https://redis.io/commands/smismember

Comment: What is the max keys I can send with this method?